# How to print a field of a struct

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to print a struct's field in C, and I have troubles with it.
I'm having 2 problems.

First, when I'm trying to print the field "courseName" of a course named "math" I get: "(null)math══════════════════════════"

Second, when I try to print the field courseNumber, it prints the courseNumber and the courseName.
can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
struct Course {
    char courseNumber[6];
    char courseName[30];
    struct Course* next;
};

struct Course* updateCoursesList(char courseDetails[], struct Course* coursesList)
{
    struct Course* head = NULL;
    int i = 6, j = 0;
    if (coursesList == NULL) {
        coursesList = (struct Course*)malloc(sizeof(struct Course));
        if (coursesList == NULL)
            return NULL;
        head = coursesList;
        strncpy(coursesList->courseNumber, courseDetails, 5);
        coursesList->next = NULL;
        while (courseDetails[i] != '\n') {
            coursesList->courseName[j] = courseDetails[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    else {
        head = coursesList;
        if (strncmp(courseDetails, coursesList->courseNumber, 5) == 0) {
            while (courseDetails[i] != '\n') {
                coursesList->courseName[j] = courseDetails[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            return head;
        }
        while (coursesList->next != NULL) {
            if (strncmp(courseDetails, coursesList->courseNumber, 5) == 0) {
                while (courseDetails[i] != '\n') {
                    coursesList->courseName[j] = courseDetails[i];
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
                return head;
            }
            else
                coursesList = coursesList->next;
        }
        coursesList->next = (struct Course*)malloc(sizeof(struct Course));
        if (coursesList->next == NULL)
            return head;
        strncpy(coursesList->next->courseNumber, courseDetails, 5);
        coursesList->next->next = NULL;
        while (courseDetails[i] != '\n') {
            coursesList->next->courseName[j] = courseDetails[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    struct Course* coursesList = NULL;
    char array[30] = "12345 math\n";
    coursesList = updateCoursesList(array, coursesList);
    printf("%s", coursesList->courseNumber);
    printf("%s", coursesList->courseName);
}
```

Comment: In C, strings need to be NUL terminated. `strncpy(coursesList->courseNumber, courseDetails, 5);` that does not result in a NUL terminated string. Need something like `coursesList->courseNumber[5] = '\0';`

Comment: Undefined behavior for out-of-bounds access.

Comment: @kaylum thank you man. It solved both of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `strncpy` for copying both your `courseNumber` and `courseName` because both are strings.

`strncpy` does not terminate the copied string with `\0` terminator, so we have add the `\0` at the end.

For your input `char array[30] = "12345 math\n";` do as follows.

```
strncpy(coursesList->courseNumber, courseDetails, 5);
coursesList->courseNumber[5] = '\0';
//since your courseName is also string, you need not do piece by piece copy
strncpy(coursesList->courseName, courseDetails+6, 5);
coursesList->courseName[5] = '\0';
```

and below code is not required in both of your `if` and `else` parts

```
while (courseDetails[i] != '\n')
{
    coursesList->courseName[j] = courseDetails[i];
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

**NOTE:** But this very weird way of reading your inputs , instead take inputs from `stdin` and use them, because the lengths may not be same for all courses.